# Implementation of sockets in a web application

Tags: java, javascript, php, sockets, web

For some time, I have wanted to do my development more efficiently and faster.  I wonder what is the best technology for implementing sockets in a web application.  Normally I use PHP and JSON for HTTP requests from the client, and I build my clients in GWT and mobile clients in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried nodeJS? its a bit different to what you've been using before but it works well.

See this tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/

and this demo - http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/08/nodejs-drawing-game/